# Web API ASP .NET / Angular2 Hosted on Azure Session doesn't work

Tags: xml, angular, c#-4.0

*Hello, first question here so if something doesn't fit tell me.*

So we develop this Web API with C# and Angular2.
One of the features needs the session to be efficient, I went through numerous topics and articles I'm stuck on this for several days.

I casually store my objet in the session like this :

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null) HttpContext.Current.Session["Object"] = myNotNullVariable;
```

Server Side, cors is enabled with EnableCors attribute(using joker * everywhere result with a cors error with front) :

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200,http://mywebapifronturl,http://mywebapibackurl",headers: "accept,content-type,origin,expires,cookie,authorization",methods: "*",exposedHeaders: "set-cookie",SupportsCredentials = true)]
[RoutePrefix("api/project")]
public class ProjectController : ApiController
```

Here is the front end request :

`myGetFunctionWhichNeedsSession(): Observable<Array<ModelModel>>{
    return this.http.get(environment.baseUrl + '/api/myController/myGetFunctionWhichNeedsSession/')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }`

Below is my WebApiConfig :

```
    public static string UrlPrefix { get { return "api"; } }
    public static string UrlPrefixRelative { get { return "~/api"; } }

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Configuration et services API Web

        // Itinéraires de l'API Web
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.EnableCors();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Then a piece of my Global.asax :

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
    {
        if (IsWebApiRequest())
        {
            HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);
        }
    }

    private bool IsWebApiRequest()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.StartsWith(WebApiConfig.UrlPrefixRelative);
    }

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started
        Session.Timeout = 10080;
    }
```

Eventually my Web.config file :

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="10080" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

When I test only Backend API with RestletClient it's alright, but when i try with my Frontend Angular sessions do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i let it here because of why not.
The source of the probleme was that in Angular, a "withcredential" parameter wasn't send to the BackEnd.